# Navigate normally from camera perspective?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

When I'm in camera view <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> and I want to navigate in the 3D-view with e.g. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> the view jumps to a completely different location.
I actually jump from *Camera Perspective* to *User Perspective*.
Can I avoid this?

Is there perhaps a way to set the "User Persp" view to the camera location and rotation?
Or a way to avoid that you when you start navigating in Camera view that you jump back to the last location in User view?

I do not mean "Lock camera to View".
I just want to start navigation from the camera's position *without moving the camera itself*.

---

Thanks for the elaborate and visualized replies.
The hacks are very clever. However, as I just want to be able to continue navigating the world starting from camera view, they take too much effort and attention.
As I've been pondering as to why this feature hasn't been added yet to Blender it became apparent that it's not that straightforward.
After all, user view and camera view are most likely in diffent perspective. User view could be in ortho view and if not, it would still be in a different focal lenght than the camera. So  a seamless navigation from your camera view would result in a changed perspective of your user view and that might be equally annoying as the problem I'm describing in my picture.
Oh well, I guess I have to get over this little limitation.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

If you wish, you can lock the Camera to the perspective view. That means that whenever you navigate in the 3D viewport the camera will 'follow' you in the view, copying the location and rotation of your navigation. In effect, in this mode it will look like you have never left the camera perspective as the dark border around the camera and the camera border itself, will remain visible.

It can be enabled in the properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) under the 'View' section:

[image]

At any point you can then disable the option and the camera will remain at the position you navigated to meaning you can use this to move you camera into position and then leave it at the desired location.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not what I mean. I don't want to move the camera itself. I just want to navigate the 3D starting from the [numpad-0] camera position.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the camera and press <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> (view selected)
2. Press <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> to enter *Camera Perspective*
3. Press <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> twice

However it will be zoomed out a bit.
I hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit of a hack, but it seems to work:

1. Enter camera view (<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>)
2. Duplicate the camera (<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>)
3. With the duplicate camera selected, press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>
4. Press <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> to exit camera view.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Without* Lock Camera To View selected, go to camera view and then just start moving around. You'll exit the camera view, but not jump to where you were before.